# Get one object of array Json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios, get

I followed this little how to to apply a simple api in nodejs. It is not quite my area of ​​expertise, I am a Computer Network Analyst and although I develop applications in C ++ (simple) and C #, I have a small doubt on how to obtain the result of an array returned by the following code:

Javascript Code using Mysql ->

```
//
 exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
 const name = req.query.name;
 var condition = name ? { name: { [Op.like]: `%${name}%` } } : null;

Customers.findAll({ where: condition })
.then(data => {
    res.send(data);;
})
.catch(err => {
  res.status(500).send({
    message:


      err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving name."
   });
 });
};
```

Access to URL to check if everything goes as expected.

```
http://10.1.1.254:8085/api/customers?name=Gabriel
```

My result:

```
  [
   {"id":6,
   "name":"Gabriel",
   "cod":10,
   "igCustomer":"1",
   "createdAt":null,
   "updatedAt":null}
   ]
```

How could I get the values ​​of name, cod, imgCustomer?

Im try;

```
axios.get(`http://10.1.1.254:8085/api/customers?name=Gabriel`).then((res) => {
let myvar = `My result:\n\n${res.data.name}`;
console.log(myvar);
})
```

Result if : Undefinid

Answer (score 2):

You can access object values in JavaScript like this...

```js
let res =   [{"id":6,
   "name":"Gabriel",
   "cod":10,
   "igCustomer":"1",
   "createdAt":null,
   "updatedAt":null}]

let name = res[0].name;
let cod = res[0].cod;
let igCustomer = res[0].igCustomer;
```

Because `res` is an array full of objects, you access an object with its location in the index, like `res[0]`.  From there you can select the key/value pair in your object by using dot notation or brackets.  Each method has its use.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
let res = [
   {"id":6,
   "name":"Gabriel",
   "cod":10,
   "igCustomer":"1",
   "createdAt":null,
   "updatedAt":null}
   ]

console.log(res[0]['name']);
console.log(res[0]['cod']);
console.log(res[0]['igCustomer']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code that you are trying to access a field that does not exists. The `res.data` will be equal to the response of your endpoint. Your response is an array, so apparently it does not have `name` field. So you need to take a particular object.

```
const user = res.data[0]; // Taking the first user.
```

Then you can access its data.

```
user.name; // Gabriel
```

Answer (score 0):

To find data from array, you can iterate that array and use find like this :

```js
let res = [
   {id:6,
   name:"Gabriel",
   cod:10,
   igCustomer:"1",
   createdAt:null,
   updatedAt:null}
   ]

let myVar = res.find((item) => {
  return item.name === 'Gabriel'
});

console.log(myVar.name);
console.log(myVar.cod);
console.log(myVar.igCustomer);
```